# Creating an updater; replacing files that are in use?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create an updater for a screenshot application I have.

I've done the main part of downloading the update, but I now need to find a way to rename the new file the same as the existing one -

**e.g.** `"NewFile.exe" > "ScreenshotApp.exe"`.

Also, I don't want to add another .exe solely for updating, just for the purpose of keeping it light and portable.

Is there any way of renaming a file that's in use?

Perhaps telling Windows to rename it AS SOON AS the application has closed itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:
Have launcher which most likely you want update that will handle updating your application as well as launching.

Option 2:
Have external exe monitoring updates and updating your app.

Option 3:
Cretate batch file that will update your app whenever your done using it.

Option 3 is the one you are looking for but it is the worst. If anything goes wrong the app wont work and if user can live without it, they wont reinstall.
Option 2 is mostly used by bigger players. They either work all the time or are scheduled.
I would do option 3, it is much easier than you think, and if you want single exe, just make your app a dll, you can update it whenever you want but launcher will stay the same. That way you can handle any errors, and fix them if there is need for it.

Option 4 would be to run installer with fresh update that will close app install update. That solution is better to buy. For $250 you can get neat stuff where it would take you a lot man hours to o something even remotely close.

Comment: Why do you think that Option #3 is bad? how about the following approach: 1- The app downloads the new executable. 2- The app creates a batch file then exits. 3- The batch waits until the old executable file to be write accessible, delete it, rename the new executable, and start it. I think it's not likely that something would go wrong.

Comment: After I had posted, I was thinking up ways in my head. One was actually a batch file, like you suggested. Have it wait until the app closes and then delete the old file, rename the new file and the new file will delete the batch file when it opens. I might go for Option 3 then! Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure with newer system but changing some files within program files may be a problem. Non-popular apps batch file may throw virus notification and block it. There are actually a lot that may go wrong. And guys think how many apps that will give you trouble at first use you endep using/

Comment: @Claudius yes you might be right about this point.. Actually -for me- I prefer using Option #2.. but I was just wondering why you think using a batch is a bad idea.